# Replacing matrix cells for corresponding row names

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, replace

I'm working with a matrix that looks like this input.

[image]

I'm trying to replace numbers on column 2 by their corresponding row name. I.e. all 1s would be replaced by row.name(matrix). Thus, I'd have the following output.

[image]

The actual matrix is too large for loop application... I'm sorry I'm using images since I found it easier to represent this on excel. I'm also sorry about being quite new at R...

Comment: `sapply(df$B, function(x) df$A[x])` or even more clever `df$A[df$B]`

Comment: Those are not row names.

Answer (score 3):

Vectorized approach (should be the fastest you can get):

```
mat <- matrix(c(letters[1:11], 1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), ncol = 2)
    colnames(mat) <- c("A", "B")
    rownames(mat) <- 1:11

> mat
   A   B  
1  "a" "1"
2  "b" "1"
3  "c" "1"
4  "d" "2"
5  "e" "2"
6  "f" "3"
7  "g" "3"
8  "h" "3"
9  "i" "4"
10 "j" "4"
11 "k" "4"


mat[, "B"] <- mat[as.numeric(mat[, "B"]), "A"]
> mat
   A   B  
1  "a" "a"
2  "b" "a"
3  "c" "a"
4  "d" "b"
5  "e" "b"
6  "f" "c"
7  "g" "c"
8  "h" "c"
9  "i" "d"
10 "j" "d"
11 "k" "d"
```

---

Or you could use `sapply`:

```
mat[, "B"] <- sapply(mat[, "B"], function(x) mat[as.numeric(x), "A"])
```

---

Edit: I've put the vectorized solution at the top, as this is clearly the faster (or even fastest?) approach.